# Как остановить опрос в telegram-bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, тестирую телеграм бота из библиотеки pyTelegramBotApi, не могу остановить опрос. Запускаю скрипт в PowerShell. Подскажите как можно его остановить, не закрывая окно консоли?

```
while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: Попробуйте нажать `Ctrl + C`? Тогда должен сработать `KeyboardInterrupt` и скрипт завершится

Comment: Ctrl + C не помогает

Answer (score 0):

в консоли
`taskkill /im python.exe /f`
закрывает все процессы python, я только так спасаюсь